# finding homology of disjoint closed balls

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If  $U \subset  \mathbb{R}^m$ and $B$ is a closed ball contained in $\mathring{U}$ (interior of $U$) with $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ are disjoint closed balls contained in $\mathring{B}$ (interior of $B$).

then how would I compute the homology group:

$$H_n\left(B \setminus \bigcup _{i=1}^n \mathring{B_i}\right)$$

Comment: What have you tried? What happens with no interior balls, or with one or two interior balls? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: It seems that $U$ serves no purpose...

Comment: You shouldn't alternate in and out of MathJax within a single expression.  See my edits. Also note the proper use of \setminus. And the exponent $m$ in $\mathbb R^m$ should not be in the scope of \mathbb. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Arthur well i know that B is contractible so has trivial homology right so this would be the case with no interior balls, but what would happen taking away one interior ball? i was hoping to do some work concerning the Long exact sequence pairing this with be boundary of the nth interior ball

Comment: If you take away one ball, then the space deformation retracts to a sphere. If you take away two balls, it deformation retracts into two spheres with a thin line connecting them. What about $3$ spheres?

Comment: AH i see thank you! @Arthur i think i have enough to work with from here